Multi controlled X (in general multi controlled Unitary) in QSharp
qiskit provide a way to apply a multicontrolled X gate (or in general any multicontrlled unitary) for exmaple the below code snippet apply the X gate on qubit dif , controlled on qubits present in dif_qubits array. Can we do the same in Qsharp?
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit
    from qiskit.circuit.library import MCXGate
    dif_qubits = [0,2,4]
    dif = 3
    qc = QuantumCircuit(5)
    qc.append(MCXGate(len(dif_qubits)), dif_qubits+[dif])

I tried this code in qsharp but it has two probems
    operation Try(n:Int) : Result[] {
      
      use q = Qubit[n];

      let dif_qubits = [q[0], q[2]];
      let target = q[1];
      Controlled X(dif_qubits, target);
      Microsoft.Quantum.Diagnostics.DumpMachine();
      let r = MeasureEachZ(q);
      ResetAll(q);
      return r     
      }


First it works with only two controlled qubit, also we have to provide a controlled qubit in the form
    [q[0],q[2]],

I am looking for a way to give dif_qubits array directly like in qiskit

Controlled is the right functor to use in this scenario. It works with an arbitrary number of qubits in the control array, did you run into any issues when trying to use a different number of controls?
When you say "give dif_qubits array directly", do you mean the indices of the qubits in the array to be used as controls?
Q# uses qubit variables as arguments to gates, including controlled gates, rather than indices, since the syntax of qubit allocation is different - you can allocate several arrays of qubits or individual qubits and use a mix of them as controls.
If you allocate all your qubits as a single array and want to refer to them using indices, you can construct the array of qubits using indices with the help of Subarray function like this:
use qs = Qubit[5];
let controls = Subarray([0, 2, 4], qs);
Controlled X(controls, qs[3]);

